# pyspark rename columns with a collected list

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a collected list I processed from a `spark df`

```
Row(m1={'WERKS': 'plant_id'}), Row(m1={'NAME1': 'plant_name'}), Row(m1={'KUNNR': 'customer_id'}), ...)
```

EG: `'WERKS'` is an existing column in my `df`, I want to rename it to `plant_id`.

I have tried `withColumnRenamed()` but I am unable to loop it to extract the `keys` and `values` from the list.

```
for i in target_fields:
    print(i["m1"].items())
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(i["m1"].items())
```

Note: `print(i["m1"].items())` results in:

```
dict_items([('WERKS', 'plant_id')])
dict_items([('NAME1', 'plant_name')])
dict_items([('KUNNR', 'customer_id')])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.items()` is a iterator. You only have one item in it but you still have to go through the whole iterator :

```py
for i in target_fields:
    for old_name, new_name in i["m1"].items():
        df = df.withColumnRenamed(old_name, new_name)
```

---

you can also try this (did not test - not sure it works) :

```py
for i in target_fields:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(*list(i["m1"].items())[0])
```